# readdirSync of node.js output nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to build a json file with all the filename within a folder, what's wrong with the code below?

```
const iconsFolder = './resources/assets/icons';
const fs = require('fs');
const jsonfile = require('jsonfile');

let json = [];
fs.readdirSync(iconsFolder, [], (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    json.push({'name': file.split('.')[0]})
  });
})

console.log(json); // empty array?
```

Answer (score 2):

`readdirSync` returns the files. You are trying to access it via a callback which will never be called. You will get it as return value:

```
var files = fs.readdirSync(iconsFolder, []);

files.forEach(file => {
    json.push({'name': file.split('.')[0]})
});
```

Perhaps you are trying to use [fs.readdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) which is asynchronous:

```
fs.readdir(iconsFolder, [], (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    json.push({'name': file.split('.')[0]})
  });
  console.log(json);
})
```

Comment: how can I write file? can I put `jsonfile.writeFile(iconsFolder ,json);` after readdir?

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use readdirSync, the code should be

```
let json = [];
let files = fs.readdirSync(iconsFolder);
files.forEach(file => {
  json.push({'name': file.split('.')[0]})
});
```

Or if you would like to use a callback, the code should be

```
let json = [];
fs.readdir(iconsFolder, (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    json.push({'name': file.split('.')[0]})
  });
});
```